# Unable to open redirected URL in UIWebview

Tags: ios, uiwebview, nsurl

I am using google RSS feed where I am getting some URL:

https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.mcphersonsentinel.com/article/20140422/SPORTS/140429875/10084/SPORTS&ct=ga&cd=CAIyAA&usg=AFQjCNG9pfoDddHHNV0gJaspzR1jv1ffKA

when I am trying to open this into uiwebview it never load the page.

if I open this in safari it says **Safari cannot open the page because too many redirects occurred**

please suggest.

Comment: I can open the same url in Firfox but not in the Chrome. totally strange !!

Answer (score 0):

Might be your URL Is not valid, for check it out use following code:

```
NSString *strURL = @"https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.mcphersonsentinel.com/article/20140422/SPORTS/140429875/10084/SPORTS&ct=ga&cd=CAIyAA&usg=AFQjCNG9pfoDddHHNV0gJaspzR1jv1ffKA";    
NSString *urlRegEx =
@"(http|https)://((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*)+([\\.|/]((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*))+";
NSPredicate *urlPredic = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx];
BOOL isValidURL = [urlPredic evaluateWithObject:strURL];

if(isValidURL)
{
    strURL = [strURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *websiteUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:websiteUrl];
    [self.webview loadRequest:urlRequest];
}
else
    NSLog(@"URL IS NOT VALID.");
```